# Getting selected attribute value of an XML Document using C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Below is my config xml file,where i have multiple username and password.From this i need to select xml nodes by `username` attribute values.

```
 <Authentication>
    <auth Userame="username1" Password ="xxxxxx"/>
    <auth Userame="username2" Password ="xxxxxxx"/>
    <auth Userame="username3" Password ="xxxxxx"/>
  </Authentication>
```

What i am trying is,I need to select the node with username2 and update the value of password for that node in xml.I am using `XmlDocument` and i can see lot of examples with XDocument for selecting attribute.Is it possible to perform this with XmlDocument in C#.

Currently i am doing with one node and for one node i implemented like below,

```
 XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Settings/Authentication/auth").Attributes["Password"].Value = password;
 XmlDoc.Save(path);
```

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: Do you have Settings element for which Authentication is child? I tried your example but with ("Authentication/auth") instead of ("Settings/Authentication/auth"). and it works

Comment: @Igor Yes,Authentication is child of Settings element.

Comment: ...and what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Igor can you tell me how to do this using xmldocument.

Comment: @har07 ,I need to select the node with username2 and update the value of password for that node in xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight modification to the XPath part of your code will do the job :

```
var username = "username2";
var xpath = String.Format("Settings/Authentication/auth[@Userame='{0}']", username);
XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath)
      .Attributes["Password"]
      .Value = password;
```

Comment: How to assign the value of textbox dynamically in place of username2.I have to assign value of username2 dynamically and update the password.

Comment: tried like this "XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Settings/Authentication/auth[@Userame="+username+"]").Attributes["Password"].Value;" getting NULLReference Execption.

Comment: updated my answer, you can change `username` variable to whatever dynamic value you want..